# File not found error on ec2 ubuntu 10.10 instance official instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I created an official ubuntu 64 bit instance 10.10 and I following the instructions given in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide but I execute this command `ec2-describe-images -o self -o amazon` I am getting file not found the executed this command 
`export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=/home/xxxxx/pk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem
export EC2_CERT=/home/xxxx/cert-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/`

Comment: That guide tells you to add those commands to your bash config. Are you using Bash as your default shell?

Comment: please, provide exact outputs for each command you've tried to execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your error message not say which file is not found (even just blank quotes)?

For Bash and the AWS Tools, the common scenarios are:

- `-bash: ec2-describe-images: command not found`

  - Implying that either the AWS Tools were not installed or your $PATH does not include them
- `Required option '-K, --private-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)`

  - Meaning you haven't exported EC2_PRIVATE_KEY
- `Required option '-C, --cert CERT' missing (-h for usage)`

  - Meaning you haven't exported EC2_CERT
- `File not found: '/path/to/cert-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem'`

  - Meaning you exported an invalid path
- `File not found: ''`

  - Likely meaning you either put a space after the equal sign on your export statement or otherwise omitted the path entirely.

Presuming you have none of the above errors, I might suggest:

1. running `ec2-describe-images --help` (it will confirm that you have the program, and provide you an overview of the commands)
2. running the command in verbose mode `ec2-describe-images -v -o self -o amazon`
3. try to run the program by passing your keys directly to it: `ec2-describe-images -K /path/to/pk/pk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem -C /path/to/cert/cert-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem -o self -o amazon`

If that fails, try to run the API tools on your own (local) machine - they don't need to run on the remote machine (and it is rare you will actually need them on the remote machine - there are much more efficient ways of getting that information if you need to script something)

For a simpler way to get essentially the same information, try ElasticFox.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious response, but it's worth a shot: Are you putting in those 'xxxxx's, or are you replacing them with your actual filenames?

Comment: I am actually replacing them with the actual file name